# jss-snapshot-serializer: jss nested selector or @media queries are not added to the json snapshot (JEST)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, jss

JSS constant:

```
const style = {
    gridItemOne : {
        "@media screen and (max-width: 577px)": {
            padding: "8%"
        },
        paddingBottom: "1%",
        paddingLeft: "1%",
        paddingTop: "2%"
        }
    link : {
        "& a" : {
            color: "#007bff"
        },
        "& a:hover" : {
            color: "#0056b3"
        }
};
```

If I change the padding: "8%" or the color of "& a", is not detected by the snapshot test however, if I change paddingBottom: "1%" is detected by the test of the snapshot.

Do you know how to add selectors or @media queries to the snapshot?

Thank you,
Daniel